# How to subscribe redux-saga to action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a problem with redux-sage. Cannot manage to subscribe to action.
I have this setup for store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux"
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga"

import rootSaga from "../config/rootSaga"
import rootReducer from "../config/rootReducer"

const effects = []

let composeEnhancers = compose

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ // eslint-disable-line no-underscore-dangle
}

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
effects.push(sagaMiddleware)

const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...effects)))
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

export default store
```

Looks like the saga middleware does not work.
I see console.log from my rootSaga but when a redux action is happening the saga doesn't work

```
export default function* searchRootSaga() {
  console.log("searchRootSaga") // I see this on start
  yield all([fork(throttle, 100, SEARCH.GET.REQUEST, getSearchThis)])
}

export function* getSearchThis(action) { 
  console.log("getSearchThis") // I dont see this
  try {
    // const response = yield call(API.getSearch, query)
    const response = dummy_data

    yield put(getSearchSuccess(response))
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(getSearchFailure("Server Err"))
  }
}
```

React dev tools shows SEARCH.GET.REQUEST action but saga is not working.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think `throttle` is a non-blocking effect itself. So you don't need to fork it. Try `yield throttle(100, SEARCH.GET.REQUEST, getSearchThis)`

Comment: @MartinKadlec ```yield all([throttle(2000, SEARCH.GET.REQUEST, getSearchThis)])``` works for me. but i found that the problem it's the redux-saga version. with v0.16 mine works but it doesn't on the new v1.0.1. can you post your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think throttle is a non-blocking effect itself. So you don't need to fork it. Try:

```
yield throttle(100, SEARCH.GET.REQUEST, getSearchThis)
```